# Could not get unknown property 'cdvMinSdkVersion' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build.gradle, cordova-plugins

So I have a old Cordova project that I want to upgrade to Android 12. But I am getting unknown property 'cdvMinSdkVersion' when building it even though I am passing the cdvMinSdkVersion as a build argument. Here is the command,

```
$cordovaPrefs = @("android-minSdkVersion", "26"), @("android-targetSdkVersion", "33"), @("android-compileSdkVersion", "33"), @("Orientation", "portrait"), @("SplashScreen", "screen"), @("AutoHideSplashScreen", "false"), @("FadeSplashScreenDuration", 800)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $cordovaPrefs.length; $i++) {
    $prefElement = $cordovaConfig.createElement("preference")
    $prefName = $cordovaConfig.createAttribute("name")
    $prefName.Value = $cordovaPrefs[$i][0]
    $prefElement.Attributes.Append($prefName)
    $prefValue = $cordovaConfig.createAttribute("value")
    $prefValue.Value = $cordovaPrefs[$i][1]
    $prefElement.Attributes.Append($prefValue)
    $cordovaConfig.widget.AppendChild($prefElement)
}
```

And here is the plugin command for browsertabs,
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/Qbix/cordova-plugin-browsertabs.git --save`

Also the build command,
`cordova build android --release -- --keystore=****** --storePassword=******** --alias=safeprofile --password=*********`

Here is the full error,

```
Script 
'~app\android\app\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-browsertabs\app-BrowserTab.gradle' 
line: 3
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not get unknown property 'cdvMinSdkVersion' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: ~app\android\app\platforms\android\gradlew -b 
!app\android\app\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug
```

As the build.gradle generated by Cordova, I can not edit that. And this error also occurs for other plugin also.
Any help will be greatly apricated.

the cdvMinSdkVersion is generated in the config.xml like this,

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="26" xmlns="" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" xmlns="" />
<preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="33" xmlns="" />
```

Also these are the values I get in the cdv-gradle-config.json file,

```
"MIN_SDK_VERSION":26,"SDK_VERSION":33,"COMPILE_SDK_VERSION":33,
```